# Set date & time through WMI in vb

Tags: datetime, vbscript, wmi

I want to set my system's date & time by reading current information from a remote computer. That computer is in a domain. I used below code to access timezone:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & ServerAddress & "\root\cimv2")
Set oRemoteItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_TimeZone")

For Each o In oRemoteItems
    ServerTime = o.StandardName
    Exit Function
Next
```

but this code is not working. I am getting access denied error (5). Please tell where am i doing some wrong? Also do i need to impersonate user because on while on workgroup --> workgroup user on both machines are same. But while on workgroup-->domain users on both systems are different. Please suggest how to impersonate and use above code?

Also, i am using net time command to set date & time but it is also failing due to access denied error.

Regards,

Comment: Have you look at this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/11/16/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-set-the-date-and-time-on-a-computer.aspx

Comment: You may need to use something like psexec to make your scripts work on a remote computer that isn't on a domain.

Comment: Thanks HK1, I knew psexec but I have few systems which dont have psexec tool. But isn't there any other way like i used above to know timezone of remote computer in workgroup? There should be some way to impersonate domain admin user and use that object to know time information through WMI. Any other thoughts also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I finally achieved it.. :)

Below code will tell you timezone, date & time of remote system irrespective of remote system being in either domain or workgroup. Only point to consider is that user running below code must be admin on workgroup or domain.

```
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(remoteserver,"root\CIMV2",adminuser,adminpassword,"MS_409","")

Set oRemoteItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_TimeZone")

For Each o In oRemoteItems
    sServerTimezone = o.StandardName
Next
```

MsgBox sServerTimezone

'Search for Win32_TimeZone on google and you will find other parameters for date & time apart from StandardName

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Dipesh